# Python - xlrd and unicodecsv

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I want to convert an Excel(xlsx) file to csv. I have coded this function to do so, but quotechart='"' is not working.

```
import xlrd
import unicodecsv

def xls_to_csv (xls_filename, csv_filename):

    wo = xlrd.open_workbook(xls_filename)
    st = wo.sheet_by_index(0)

    fl = open(csv_filename,"wb")
    csv_out = unicodecsv.writer(fl, encoding='utf-8', quotechart='"')

    for row_number in range (st.nrows):
        csv_out.writerow(st.row_values(row_number))

    fl.close()
xls_to_csv('PT_BR.POSTP.20160508_vx27.xlsx','prueba.csv')
```

current output:

```
Category,Term,POS,Term,POS,Term,POS,,,,
A001,atendimento,sust,concessionário,sust,não,adv,bom,adj,,
...
```

desired output:

```
"Category","Term","POS","Term","POS","Term","POS"
"A001","atendimento","sust","concessionário","sust","não","adv","bom","adj"
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this in csv file writer object instead of `quotechart='"'`:

```
quoting = unicodecsv.QUOTE_ALL
```

not tried though.